# Reload the React-Table with button

Tags: typescript, react-table, react-tsx

Goal:
Press the button reload in order to reload the content of the react-table.

Problem:
The same code and Iam using at Stackblitz and local dev computer, it doesn't work.

What part am I missing?

Info:
*New in react-table
*Using Typescript

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cbvmnt

[image: From VS code]

Thank you!

---

app.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTable, Column, useSortBy } from 'react-table';
import axios from 'axios';

const columns: Column<Data>[] = [
  {
    Header: 'login',
    accessor: 'login',
  },
  {
    Header: 'id',
    accessor: 'id',
  },
  {
    Header: 'node id',
    accessor: 'node_id',
  },
  {
    Header: 'type',
    accessor: 'type',
  },
];

interface Data {
  login: number;
  id: string;
  node_id: string;
  type: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  React.useMemo(
    () =>
      handleData().then((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setData(res);
        }, 1000);
      }),
    []
  );

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable<Data>({ columns, data }, useSortBy);

  async function handleData() {
    const handleDataaa = async () => {
      const resp = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users');
      return await resp.data;
    };

    return Promise.resolve(handleDataaa());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleData();
  }, []);

  const clickclick = () => {
    axios.get<Data[]>('https://api.github.com/users').then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickclick}>Reload</button>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {console.log(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                  {column.render('Header')}
                  <span>
                    {' '}
                    {column.isSorted
                      ? column.isSortedDesc
                        ? ' '
                        : ' '
                      : ''}{' '}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
          {rows.length === 0 && (
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={2}>loading...</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

react-table.d.tsx

```
import {
  UseSortByColumnOptions,
  UseSortByColumnProps,
  UseSortByInstanceProps,
  UseSortByOptions,
  UseSortByState,
} from 'react-table';

declare module 'react-table' {
  export interface TableOptions<D extends object> extends UseSortByOptions<D> {}

  export interface TableInstance<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByInstanceProps<D> {}

  export interface TableState<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByState<D> {}

  export interface Column<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByColumnOptions<D> {}

  export interface ColumnInstance<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByColumnProps<D> {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong typing for your state and TypeScript is warning you about it.

When you pass a default value of `[]` in `useState`, TypeScript assumes that there will never be anything within the array, hence the `never[]` type. You need to do `useState<Data[]>([])`, which will tell TypeScript the correct type for the state.